# Groovy find specific word in a text file

Tags: groovy

i'm using soapui for web service test and i want to find a specific word in my response file which is text file.
i found codes for find and replace but i want only find and display some specific word from my text file.
i tried to modify this code and i need some help please.
suppose i have a text file with Hello world and i want to find only "world" and create anothe with only "word"

```
def copy(source, dest, Closure replaceText){
    dest.write(find(source.text))
}

def source = new File('source.txt') //Hello World
find(source){
    it.findAll ('World')
}
```

Comment: Sorry...  You want to find a word in a text file?  Or you want to copy a text file, and print out if it contains a word?  Or you want to copy a file replacing a word?  Not sure from your question + example code

Comment: Hi, i want to find a specific word in a text file.

Comment: What do you mean by *find*? Do you want to know if the word exists in the text file (boolean) or do you want to know where in the file the word is located (Range or offset with length)? Then again, your example suggests you want to search/replace a word and then write out the file with the word replaced.

Comment: Once you have or haven't found this word, what is your goal?

Comment: once i have this word, i want to create a text file which contains this word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code sample is not very clear, but I guess you'll find your solution when you take a look at the regexp features of groovy:

http://mrhaki.blogspot.de/2009/09/groovy-goodness-matchers-for-regular.html

Comment: This is not an answer, it's just a reference to a source. Please complete more the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
def copy(source, dest, term){
    if(source.getText("UTF-8").find(term)){
        dest.write(term)
    }
}

def source = new File('source.txt') //Hello World
def dest = new File('dest.txt')
copy(source, dest, "World")
```